# How to capture file upload data from web page external to an ASP.NET site using .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I'm well aware of how to get files from the client to the server using standard ASP.NET techniques, however, I have a need to be able to retrieve data from a third party web page written in basic html and process the file data in an asp.net web application.

So if the basic html looks like this...

```
<form id="form1" action="WebForm.aspx" method="post">

        <input name="fileUpload1" type="file" enctype="multipart/form-data" />

        <input type="submit" value="click" />

    </form>
```

How do I retrieve the file data in the page referenced in the action attribute of the form. So far I have tried the code below, which allows me to access the file name - but not the byte stream of the file.

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
        {
            string fileName = Request.Form["fileUpload1"];

            // No files appear in the request.files collection in code below.

            foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                HttpPostedFile hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFile;
                if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)
                    continue;
                string savedFileName = Path.Combine(
                   AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,
                   Path.GetFileName( hpf.FileName ) );
                hpf.SaveAs( savedFileName );
            }
        }
```

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing... are you entering http://www.someserver.com/filename.html in the "File" input box and then submitting the form? 'Cos if you are, that won't work, because that's just not how File inputs behave :)

Comment: Here's some background on file input elements that may help:
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html

Comment: Maybe you should add enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute to your form tag

Comment: Thanks for the comments, the code works fine with Darin Dimitrov's adjustment.

@Dylan Beattie - could you elaborate? It seems this does work, unless you know a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your form is incorrect. The `enctype` parameter should be on the `form` tag:

```
<form id="form1" action="WebForm.aspx" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="fileUpload1" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="click" />
</form>
```

Comment: Ooops! Thanks very much for the spot.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to retrieve a file or resource from a remote (third-party) server during your Page_Load code, you don't need to use a file upload form.

Try this instead:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
        var html = client.DownloadString("http://www.google.com/");
        File.WriteAllText("filename", html);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is not a ASP.NET form and you have no control over it, you will need to use a 3rd party component like [Softartisans FileUp](http://fileup.softartisans.com/). I am sure there are other controls like it. A few others are mentioned on the [Learn More about Uploading Files!](https://web.archive.org/web/20180312071127/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com:80/webtech/LearnMore/Upload.asp) page.